# Only get active products from table related to category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got 2 tables:

```
1 Category
- cID
- Name
- Active

2 Products
- pID
- Name
- category_id
- active
```

This is want i want:
I want a list from categories that ONLY have ACTIVE products.

Thanks in advance

SOLUTION:
SELECT DISTINCT category.* FROM category INNER JOIN products ON category.id = products.c_id WHERE products.active = 0 ORDER BY category.id DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest construction like this
IMHO, it's syntax shows what you really want to see - all categories that have active products

```
select C.cID, C.Name, C.Active
from Category as C
where C.cID in (select distinct T.category_id from Products as T where T.Active = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume `Products.Active = 1` means active state.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Category c
INNER JOIN Products p ON c.CID = p.category_id
GROUP BY c.CID
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(IF(p.Active = 1, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Products
Join Category on Category.ciD = Products.category_id
WHERE Category.Active = 1 AND Products.Active =1
```

This is assuming your active columns are just 1 or 0. Otherwise adjust according to what values you're storing there.

Comment: I'm still getting results where products.active = 0. I used almost the same SQL as you did but just with INNER JOIN. All my categorys are active but can have inactive products. So i want to only show the categories with active products in it.

Comment: What is the value you use in the active column for an active product or category?

Comment: I got it working now:
SELECT DISTINCT category.* FROM category INNER JOIN products ON category.id = products.c_id WHERE products.active = 0 ORDER BY category.id DESC